# Radical identity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x\in\{\pm1\}$ hold true.

Is it true that for every $\epsilon\in(-1,1)$ we have $x=\frac{x+\epsilon}{\sqrt[2k]{(x+\epsilon)^{2k}}}$ at every $k\in\Bbb Z\backslash\{0\}$?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we have the equivalence;

$$\tag{1} x\in\{\pm1\} \Leftrightarrow x=sign(x).$$

The RHS can be transformed into

$$\tag{2}\frac{x+\epsilon}{\sqrt[2k]{(x+\epsilon)^{2k}}}=\frac{x+\epsilon}{|x+\epsilon|}= sign(x+\epsilon)$$

Due to (1) and (2), the question becomes : does the following sentence is true

$$\forall x, \ \forall \epsilon, \ \ sign(x)=sign(x+\epsilon) \ ?$$

The answer is evidently false : it suffices to take $x=-1$ and $\epsilon=2$ ; in this case, the LHS is $-1$, whereas the RHS is $+1$.

Remark : the interpretation of $\forall k\in\Bbb Z\backslash\{0\}$ somewhat puzzles me, in particular due to its position at the rear of what has to be proven.

Comment: $x\in\{\pm1\} \implies x\neq-\frac12$. I updated something else ($\epsilon\in(-1,1)$).

Comment: You are right !!!... I correct my counter example...